# How to write a string into a .txt file in MIPs Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, file-writing

I am having trouble writing a string into a file in MIPs. I want to write "Hello World!" to the file but instead it wrote "效汬⁯潗汲Ⅴ䌀畯摬❮⁴灏湥映汩e慃⁮灯湥映汩" which I'm pretty sure is a mix of characters with a specific unicode. I don't know why it does that.

Here's the code I have. What am I doing wrong?:

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    # Open file
    li $v0,13           # open_file syscall code = 13
    la $a0,fileName # get the file name
    li $a1,1            # file flag = write
    syscall
    move $s6,$v0        # save the file descriptor 

    #write into the file
    li $v0, 15              # write_file syscall code = 15
    move $a0, $s6          # file descriptor (fileName)
    la $a1, helloWorld      # the text that will be written in the file
    li $a2, 44              # file size? 
    syscall

    #close the file
    li $v0, 16      # close_file syscall code
    syscall

    j Exit

Exit:

.data
fileName: .asciiz "F:/HelloWorld.txt"
helloWorld: .asciiz "Hello World!"      # This will be written into the file
```

Comment: Doesn't your program also crash after closing the file?  There are no instructions after `Exit`, so it starts decoding whatever garbage or padding comes next in the `.text` section.  (And BTW, you don't need to `j` over a blank line.  Execution would fall through to `Exit:` if you removed the `j Exit`.)  Anyway, that's unrelated to your bug.  Check your system call arguments.  But `44` looks larger than the length of `.asciiz "Hello World!"`

Comment: I finally figured out the problem after many hours of pondering. It turns out that I forgot to close the file descriptor after using the close_file syscall code: `move $a0, $s6`. It finally printed "Hello World" after that.